# Orbited vs Orbited2

Tags: python, orbited

I want to use Orbited to my chat. I also found Orbited2. What is the difference? Is Orbited dead or not? I want to use solid solution and don't worry it will be closed or not supported.
I haven't found any tutorial to Orbited2 - even their documentation is weak :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbited is no longer supported or maintained, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orbited-users/MhEIjOxwEKM/I_fMdLGGAJYJ).